# C# Youtube Search Api Using Advanced Search

Tags: c#, youtube

I want to learn search api in youtube. I used example project and I want to improve it. Example order, video duration

```html
 searchListRequest.VideoDuration = SearchResource.ListRequest.VideoDurationEnum.Medium;
```

This giving
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.

This is giving error. How I will use VideoDuration

I tried

```html
searchListRequest.VideoDuration = "Medium";
```

This gave
Error   CS0029  Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'Google.Apis.YouTube.v3.SearchResource.ListRequest.OrderEnum?'

My All Code is;

```html
   var youtubeService = new YouTubeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                ApiKey = "xxxx",
                ApplicationName = this.GetType().ToString()
            });

            var searchListRequest = youtubeService.Search.List("snippet");
            searchListRequest.Q = "Google"; // Replace with your search term.
            searchListRequest.MaxResults = 50;
            switch (videoduration.SelectedIndex) //Combobox
            {
                case 0 :
                    searchListRequest.VideoDuration = SearchResource.ListRequest.VideoDurationEnum.Any;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    searchListRequest.VideoDuration = SearchResource.ListRequest.VideoDurationEnum.Short__;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    searchListRequest.VideoDuration = SearchResource.ListRequest.VideoDurationEnum.Medium;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    searchListRequest.VideoDuration = SearchResource.ListRequest.VideoDurationEnum.Long__;
                    break;
            }

    

            // Call the search.list method to retrieve results matching the specified query term.
            var searchListResponse = await searchListRequest.ExecuteAsync();

            List<string> videos = new List<string>();
            List<string> channels = new List<string>();
            List<string> playlists = new List<string>();

            // Add each result to the appropriate list, and then display the lists of
            // matching videos, channels, and playlists.
            foreach (var searchResult in searchListResponse.Items)
            {
                richTextBox1.AppendText(searchResult.Snippet.Title + Environment.NewLine);
                richTextBox1.AppendText("https://youtu.be/"+ searchResult.Id.VideoId + Environment.NewLine);
                richTextBox1.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);

            }
```